# Ho to not load a head script in dev

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

In my nuxt.config.js I have a script in the html head config.

```js
export default {
  // Target: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-target
  target: 'static',

  // Global page headers: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head
  head: {
    title: 'My cool Website !',
    script: [
      { 
        hid: "thesemetrics",
        src: "https://unpkg.com/thesemetrics@latest",
        async: true,
        type: "text/javascript",
     },
     { src: 'https://identity.netlify.com/v1/netlify-identity-widget.js'}
    ]
  },
  // ...
}
```

Is there a way to not load this script when I am in Dev Mode ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the function form of `head`, and conditionally add these scripts based on `process.env.NODE_ENV`:

```js
export default {
  head() {
    const productionScripts =
      process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
        ? [
            { 
              hid: "thesemetrics",
              src: "https://unpkg.com/thesemetrics@latest",
              async: true,
              type: "text/javascript",
            },
            { src: 'https://identity.netlify.com/v1/netlify-identity-widget.js'}
          ]
        : []

    return {
      title: 'My cool Website !',
      script: [
        // other scripts to always load here

        ...productionScripts
      ]
    }
  },
  // ...
}
```